# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[32, 500, 800, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 500 channels instead

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am working on an object detection project. I am getting the following error:

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[32, 500, 800, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 500 channels instead

The section I think is causing the issue is:

```
# cnn_model.py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import pdb

class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)  # Expects 3 input channels (RGB)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

        # No need to define expected_in_features here in the constructor

        # Adjust in_features based on the output size of your conv layers
        # Assuming your last conv layer output size is (32, 250, 400)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 250 * 400, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        #pdb.set_trace()
        print(f"Input shape to conv1: {x.shape}")
        x = self.pool(torch.relu(self.conv1(x)))

        # Calculate expected_in_features based on the output size of the previous layers
        expected_in_features = x.size(1) * x.size(2) * x.size(3)  # Calculate it based on the current shape

        x = x.view(-1, expected_in_features)

        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
```

Comment: you have defined the first convolutional layer as `nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)`, which means it expects an input with `3 channels (RGB)`. However, the error message indicates that the input you're providing has `500 channels` instead.

Comment: Thank you Sauron,

However, when I check the shape of my images I can see they are in RGB (3 channels), but I am still getting this error.